# How to compute the integral $\int_0^\infty \arctan\left(\frac 4x\right)\sin(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to compute the definite integral $$\int_0^\infty \arctan\left(\frac 4x\right)\sin(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

My answer is below.

Comment: If you are trying to use the "Answer your own question, QnA style", you should have clarified that rather than saying "attempt".

Comment: the main thing is that $\arctan \frac{4}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}  - \arctan  \frac{x}{4}.$ Then integration by parts needs the integral of $\frac{\cos 4t}{1 + t^2}$ which is $\frac{\pi}{2 e^4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$I\overset{\text{Def.}}=\int_0^\infty \arctan\left(\frac 4x\right)\sin(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ Note that the integral is indeed well-defined, as for instance the substitution $y=\arctan\left(\frac4x\right)$ shows.

Integration by parts gives $$I=\left[-\cos(x)\arctan\left(\frac4x\right)\right]^{\infty}_0-4\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx = \frac\pi2-4\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Now, since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx=0$,
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx 
&= \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx
\\&=\frac12\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx+i \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx\right)
\\&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp(ix)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx.
\end{split}\end{equation}

After [Jordan's Lemma](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_von_Jordan), if $\gamma_R$ denotes a semi-circular contour with radius $R$, i.e. $$\gamma=\gamma_1 \text{ and then }\gamma_2,$$ where $\gamma_1$ is the path for $[-R,R]$ and $\gamma_2$ is the path for $\{z\in\mathbb C: \lvert z\rvert  = R, \operatorname{Im}(z)\geq0\}$, then

$$\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp(ix)}{x^2+16}\,\mathrm dx=\frac12\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{\exp(iz)}{z^2+16}\,\mathrm dz\overset{\text{Residue Theorem}}=\frac12\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{\exp(iz)}{z^2+16},z=4i\right)=\frac{\pi}{8e^4}.$$

In conclusion,

$$\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{I=\frac\pi2-\frac\pi{2e^4}.}$$

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution $$I=\int\frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+16}\, dx=\int\frac{e^{ix}}{(x+4i)(x-4i)}\, dx$$
$$I=\frac i 8\int \Bigg[\frac{e^{ix}}{x+4 i}-\frac{e^{ix}}{x-4 i}\Bigg]\,dx$$
$$I=\frac i {8e^4} \left(e^8 \text{Ei}(i x-4)-\text{Ei}(i x+4)\right)$$

So, for the definite integral
$$\frac i {8e^4}\Big[i \left(e^8-1\right) \pi-\text{Ei}(4)+e^8 (\text{Ei}(-4)+i \pi )\Big]=-\frac{i \left(e^8 \text{Ei}(-4)+\text{Ei}(4)+i \pi \right)}{8 e^4}$$
$$\Re(I)=\frac{\pi }{8 e^4}$$